# Do MySQL LOCK and UNLOCK commands get replicated?

Tags: mysql, replication, table-locking

I have a database that is replicated to a slave.

I have a process that updates a MyISAM table in the master database every minute. It does so by LOCKing the table, DELETEing the relevant entries, INSERTing the updated entries and then UNLOCKing the table. The updated entries do not necessarily map to the previous entries (i.e. one minute it could be 5 records, the next time 10 records, the next time 2 records for a particular identifier)

Every now and then a SELECT query on the slave in this table returns no results. The only thing I can think of is that the LOCK and UNLOCK table commands are not getting through to the slave and occasionally the SELECT query occurs after the DELETE but before the INSERT.

Is this possible, or are LOCK and UNLOCK also sent to the slave? I can't think what else could be causing it and I haven't been able to reproduce it with intent, I just see it every now and then.

Comment: Use `mysqlbinlog` to dump the binlog -- that will answer the question.

Comment: How many statements are you executing?  You could (1) load new stuff in tmp table; (2) lock; (3) 1 multi-table DELETE (reaching into the tmp table to see what to delete; (4) INSERT..SELECT to put rest in; (5) UNLOCK.  That might be faster.

Comment: It's not many statements, the tmp table approach might work

Comment: couldn't see any LOCK statements in the mysqlbinlog, so I guess it doesn't

Comment: Sounds like you need to switch to InnoDB.

Comment: Oh, one more question -- Statement Based Replication?  Or Row Based?

Comment: A good question to which I don't know the answer. I followed the [MySQL guide for how to set up replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication.html), so whichever that is!

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'binlog_format';`

Comment: I have tried to lock a table in server A (master), a second transaction in same server was blocked, but a third transaction to server B (another master) was not blocked, so finally it seems locking doesn't work with replication.